# Find four numbers where first three are in AP and last three are in GP

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find 4 numbers whose first three numbers are in a.p. and last three numbers are in g.p..if sum of first and fourth is 11, and second and third number sum is 10.

Can't seem to find a solution to this. Any help?

Comment: If you require them to be integers, then you need $b$ to be a divisor of $a^2$.

Comment: But they have to be integers since I know the answer which is 2, 4, 6, 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the sequence be $$a, b, 10-b, 11-a$$

So we have $$b-a=(10-b)-b\tag{1}$$

and

$$(10-b)^2=b(11-a)\tag{2}$$

From $(1)$, you can express $a$ in terms of $b$ and substitute inside $(2)$ and solve a quadratic equation for $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Like any word problem, define variables and write equations to reflect what you are told.  Call the four numbers $a,b,c,d$. Write an equation that says $a,b,c$ are in arithmetic progression:  $c-b=b-a$.  Write an equation that says $b,c,d$ are in geometric progression.  Left to you.  Again, sum of first and fourth is $11$, so $a+d=11$.  The next is left to you.  You will wind up with four equations in four unknowns.  Siong Thye Goh's answer incorporates some of the equations along the way, which works well when some of the equations are simple, like here.